# 7 - Can't update page titles

Tags: theming, hooks

I'm currently working on a project on which I'm trying to dynamically shorten the pages titles as following:

`"This is very long text blahblahblah | Site Name"` becomes `"This is very ... | Site Name"` but the rendered page doesn't take this into account.

Here's my problem: I tried several hooks to implement this behaviour, using `hook_menu_alter()`, `hook_preprocess_html()`, `hook_node_preprocess()`, etc. and I followed the indications given to update the pages titles when using these hooks, but it always falls back to using the original long title.

Actually, when I set the arrays accurate keys/values, would it be `$vars['head_title']`, `$vars['title']`, etc. I can var_dump the array and verify the needed variable is updated, but the title is untouched. Using `drupal_set_title($new_title)` didn't help either.

I'm quite puzzled; would this be because I'm using Custom Field, Metatag, or a specific module? Or would this be because I'm not updating the page at the correct moment during its generation? Drupal is somehow new to me!

Thanks a lot :)

~Steph

Comment: I want know how you have created page by (view,panel or something else)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK! After going back and forth between var_dump's, installed modules list and hooks, I discovered that the ONLY hook that will update the page's tags is `hook_metatag_metatags_view_alter(&$output)`, in which something like this needs to be done:

```
$output['title']['#attached']['metatag_set_preprocess_variable'][0][2] = "Custom title";
```

My n00b diagnosis is that this hook is called right after the last Metatag module's function that rebuilds the metatags from scratch, and therefore it's the only one that matters.

Hope this will help others! :)

~Steph

Answer (score 0):

Did you try [template_preprocess_page](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21theme.inc/function/template_preprocess_page/7.x)? You can modify the $variables['title'] value there. 
Inside your theme's template.php file,

```
function YOUR-THEME_preprocess_page(&$variables) {
  $variables['title'] = YOUR-TRUNCATE-FUNCTION($variables['title']) . ' | ' . $variables['site_name'];
}
```